# Red5 exception creating connection

Tags: red5

Red5 was working alright for me, then I decided to upgrade to the latest version. But the new version is showing me an error. I am running a simple client App. When I try to connect I see the exception even if I am connecting to a different app, connection.connect("rtmp://localhost/crazyName") it'will show the exception in this case too. Please someone who can help me with this.

```
package org.red5.core;

    import org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory;
    import org.red5.server.adapter.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter;
    import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
    import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
    //import org.slf4j.Logger;

    /**
    * Sample application that uses the client manager.
    * 
    * @author The Red5 Project (red5@osflash.org)
    */
     public class Application extends MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter {

    //private static Logger log =     Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        //log.info("appConnect");
        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        //log.info("disconnect");
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    }

    }


client
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var connection:NetConnection;

            public function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent) : void {
                // setup connection code
                connection = new NetConnection();
                connection.connect("rtmp://localhost/Project");
                connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnectionNetStatus);
                connection.client = this;   
            }

            public function onConnectionNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent) : void {
                // did we successfully connect
                if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
                    Alert.show("Successful Connection", "Information");
                } else {
                    Alert.show("Unsuccessful Connection", event.info.code);
                }
            }

        ]]>
     </mx:Script>

    </mx:Application>



                        [WARN] [NioProcessor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Exception creating connection
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rtmpMinaConnection' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'deadlockGuardScheduler' of bean class [org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection]: Bean property 'deadlockGuardScheduler' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:350) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnectionInstance(RTMPConnManager.java:306) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:166) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:56) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.createRTMPMinaConnection(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:297) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionCreated(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:61) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:772) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$700(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:913) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionCreated(IoFilterAdapter.java:74) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:452) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:211) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:538) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:505) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1113) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'deadlockGuardScheduler' of bean class [org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection]: Bean property 'deadlockGuardScheduler' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1076) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:930) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
[WARN] [NioProcessor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Force close - session: 3
[WARN] [NioProcessor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Force close - session: 3
[INFO] [NioProcessor-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Close already forced on this session: 3
```

Comment: There's a mismatch in the configuration files. Do a diff with the latest to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know how to do a diff. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: I uninstalled Red5 and reinstalled it and I have the same thing going on.

Comment: I'll be adding a new prerelease (snapshot) in a few minutes, you should download that zip/tarball and give it a try.

Comment: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases/tag/v1.0.7-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Ok cool. I always use the installer so I wonder if there is any guide to install this one.

Comment: Where can I find older installers of Red5? 1.0.6 SNAPSHOT won't work for me anymore.

Comment: Apache only has that version available and Red5.org doesn't have any of the previous builds available. I had some, but mega.nz removed them. You'll have to build it yourself most likely.

Comment: Alright, I just need some pointer as to how to build it. Please?

Comment: It is definitely an issue with 1.0.6 SNAPSHOT. I installed 1.0.1 and it works. I just need to know how to build Red5 1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: There is a howto, but its for building the windows installer on ubuntu https://github.com/Red5/installer/blob/master/windows/howto.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. but I comment this line in .../conf/red5-core.xml:

> property name="deadlockGuardScheduler" ref="deadlockGuardScheduler"

It worked for me...

Comment: Good, I will try that.

Comment: Do you know how to access Red5 outside the localhost? Every time I type http://myip:5080 it won't connect. It will work with localhost and 127.0.0.1 only. I tried changing webapp.virtualHosts to my public ip but nothing. I also tried changing red5.properties.

Comment: In red5.properties try change http.host=(yourip) and rtmp.host=(yourip)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that, however it wouldn't work. In a moment of frustration I used 0.0.0.0 for http.host and rtmp.host and it worked.

Comment: I updated the last release https://github.com/Red5/red5-server and It worked! I dont have problem with RTMPConnManager